# Android: Async task parallel execution issue

Tags: android

There is Async Task which is called simulateneously for different cases in a function
 
 
Currently what is hapening : After doinBackground for Task 2  is executed when onPostExecute for Task 2 is called it returns the list containing the  output corresponding to both the Task1 and Task2 as mentioned below
 
Actual O/P
onPostExecute: /path/Test1.txt
onPostExecute: /path/Test2.txt

Expected O/P
onPostExecute: /path/Test2.txt

How we can maintain the List in Post execute corresponding to each case independently(Currently this is the Static list)

---

Async task class -->

```
static ArrayList<String> listOfCopiedFiles = new ArrayList<>();

 protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
boolean sucssees_fail = true;
listOfCopiedFiles.clear();

sucssees_fail = copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(srccopy, dst);

 //copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(srccopy, dst) : Returns Boolean and add the file in    "listOfCopiedFiles" which is static array list

}


 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result)
        {   Log.d(TAG,"delegate.onSuccess");
            delegate.onSuccess(ServiceIntent, listOfCopiedFiles);
       // on success passes the list of files 
        }

}
```

Calling Class -->

```
 case Type1:
    srcCopydir = Dir1
    copyfilename = file1;               
    copyFilesAsyncTask.execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
     break;  
 case Type2:              
    srcCopydir = Dir2
    copyfilename = file2;
    copyFilesAsyncTask.execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
    break;

case Type3:
    srcCopydir = Dir3;
    copyfilename = file3
    copyFilesAsyncTask.execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
    break;

 case Type4:
    srcCopydir = Dir3;
    copyfilename = file3
    copyFilesAsyncTask.execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
    break;
```

This calss recieves the intent  by reading parsed xml which contains for all the types mentioned above

Everytime intent is received new object for Async task is created.

Issue : 
While task for issue type1 is ongoing (doInBackground), intent for other "case" is received hence execution starts for other case as well

what is happening sometimes before "onPostExecute" for Case1 is called Case 2 completes and in  case1 it gives the o/p i.e. "listOfCopiedFiles" which is expected for case2

I tried clearing the "listOfCopiedFiles" in "onPostExecute" as soon as  delegate.onSuccess(ServiceIntent, listOfCopiedFiles) is called but it doesn't seems to be working

```
Boolean chk;
  delegate.onSuccess(ServiceIntent, listOfCopiedFiles);
  for(String list :listOfCopiedFiles){             
   chk = listOfCopiedFiles.remove(list);

   }
```

Also tried copying the listOfCopiedFiles in temprorary array list in "onPostExecute" and clearing it immediately as soon as controls comes in "onPostExecute" but it's also not working

```
  Boolean chk;
  chk= copyPathTempList.addAll(listOfCopiedFiles);
   listOfCopiedFiles.clear();

  delegate.onSuccess(ServiceIntent, copyPathTempList);
  copyPathTempList.clear();
```

Comment: Please post some code. Asking a question like that will help no one, especially you trying to find an answer

Comment: Also work on making your question clearer, what are you trying to do? what is the context? you might find out from answers that your approach is wrong in the first place

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is improper since From the AsyncTask API docs:

Threading rules say,

**The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)**